# Aplicar un imagen con un hover en css

Tags: css, css3

con que propiedad podría lograr este efecto en la imagen haciendo usado de hover? o necesitarla usar js??
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CODIGO:
git@github.com:Ronnal-Zp/cardNftComponent.git

Comment: Adjunta el código para hacer pruebas. Un background-color: rbga(x,x,x,x.x); en el hover, podría ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo yo que lo que quieres es que al hacer hover, aparezca por encima un background con cierta transparencia que siga permitiendo ver la imagen. Si es así se me ocurre que con el pseudoelemento `::before` y `opacity` lo puedes conseguir, te dejo un código.

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.wrapper::before{
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    background-color: rgb(0, 194, 129);
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper:hover::before{
    opacity: .6 ;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/05/18/10/butterfly-7303688_960_720.jpg" alt="img">
   </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Juan estoy probando tu codigo pero no me va, ya actualice mi pregunta y agregue el link del proyecto, mira si puedes echarle un ojo porfa

Comment: ya lo solucione, envolví mi imagen un un div para poder hacer el efecto y agregue un z-index para que se ponga encima de la imagen

Comment: Genial entonces si solucionaste tu problema, con los z-index tienes que tener cierto cuidado, si por ejemplo tienes botones o algo por el estilo y no está bien maquetado el componente puedes hacer que sin querer dejen de funcionar ciertos elementos. Un saludo.